# How to prove that Lambda Calculus term does not have normal form?

Tags: lambda-calculus

> In 1958 Curry proved that if the leftmost reduction of a λ-term $X_1$ is
> infinite, then all reductions starting at X1 can be continued for
> ever, i.e. $X_1$ has no normal form.

How to show that the leftmost reduction is infinite?

Do I understand correctly that if at some point of reduction of term $T$ we meet a term $T_j$ that was already occurred previously ($T_j = T_i, i<j$) then term $T$ does not have a normal form? Meaning that reduction made a loop.

$T \to ... \to T_i \to ... \to T_j$, $T_i=T_j$ (intentionally, for example: $SII(SII)=SII(SII)$) implies $T$ does not have normal form?

So we can use quasi-leftmost reduction to show this looping and prove infinite reduction?

Quasi-leftmost reduction vs leftmost reduction [description](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4261895/sequencing-function-applications-in-beta-reduction/4262975#4262975).

[image]

Comment: What's the difference between leftmost reduction and quasi-leftmost reduction?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco I have included the difference in the question.